# test class code covarage:i am not able to code covareage for execute method

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

global class agreementupdate implements Database.Batchable, Database.Stateful{

```
global Integer recordsProcessed = 0; //for debugging, to find out the number of records processed
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    Date tdy = System.today();
    return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id, Service_Contract_Expired__c FROM Asset WHERE Service_Contract_Type__c != NULL and Service_Contract_Expiration_Date__c <=: tdy AND Service_Contract_Expired__c = FALSE');
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Asset> scope){
    //process batch of Asset records
    List<Asset> Assets = new List<Asset>();
    for(Asset asst : scope){
        asst.Service_Contract_Expired__c = TRUE;
        Assets.add(asst);
        recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;
    }
    Update Assets;
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    }
```

}

### Test class:

@IsTest

private class agreementupdateTest{

@isTest static void updateExpiredRecords(){

```
Date tdy = System.today();

Account testAccount = new Account (Name = 'Asset Account', BillingCountry = 'United Kingdom');
insert testAccount;

List<Asset> AssetList = new List<Asset>();

for(Integer i=0; i<5; i++){
    AssetList.add(new Asset(
    Name = 'Test'+i,
    AccountId = testAccount.Id,
    CurrencyIsoCode = 'GBP',
    Service_Contract_Type__c = 'Type'+i,
    Service_Contract_Expiration_Date__c = tdy ));
    }
    insert AssetList;


    Test.startTest();
    agreementupdateupExp = new agreementupdate();

    Database.executeBatch(upExp,100);
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertEquals(5, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Asset WHERE Service_Contract_Expired__c = TRUE]);

}
```

}

Comment: I suspect the Service_Contract_Expired__c field might be set to true when you create the asset test records. Can you do a system.debug on the Service_Contract_Expired__c field after your asset test records are inserted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For testing purposes, you can invoke directly the execute() method:

```
    List<Asset> inp = new List<Asset>(){};
    Test.startTest();
    agreementupdate d= new agreementupdate();
    agreementupdate.execute(null, inp);
    Test.stopTest();
```